# Vuforia Unity Native iOS integration crashing on startup

Tags: xcode, react-native, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have created a simple Vuforia project in unity for model tracking and it's working fine on Editor and also on iOS build.Now when I am trying to integrate in Native iOS app its getting crash on starting the unity app from native.

I have followed the following steps for the Native integration which is working fine without Vuforia:
[NativeIosApp Integration Documentation](https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-ios-app.685219/)

Can anyone give me the further steps or summary on how to integrate Vuforia in this native iOS app.

I have followed some suggestions and Copy the Framework folder of com.ptc.vuforia.engine in nativeIosApp folder and add it in Embedded Content in Xcode so far and need further steps and guidance.